# Lost gmail address for GCP account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I have a .json credentials file to use GCP API's but can't remember the google account used to create the project.

I have the project ID and service account details - is it possible to retrieve the gmail account?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of linking the credentials.json file back to the account that created the project.

You might want to try going though all the email address you have and checking them.  Or you could just create a new project with new credentials.